# Cambiar tamaño imagen CSS

Tags: html, css

he intentado cambiar el tamaño de una imagen en CSS pero solo cambia la primera vez,y el resto de veces no cambia su tamaño.
La verdad no se que este haciendo mal,si alguien es tan amable de ayudarme.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero sus respuestas :)

Comment: En realidad el css que pones aplica un tamaño al elemento `div` no a la imagen. Habría que ver el código completo y cómo tratas de cambiar el tamaño cada vez. Si pudieses poner el código completo para reproducir el problema sería más fácil.

Comment: Qué significa que cambia la primera vez? ¿Cómo debiera cambiar la segunda vez, si no hay (en tu código) ningún cambio en el HTML ni en el CSS?

Comment: Aparte de lo que dicen los compañeros. Una observación en left y top, deberías usar una medida no solo el número, puede ser px, %, em, etc. Lo otro es que te recomiendo poner tu código para entender mucho mejor tu problema, ya que no consigo verlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si el problema es que le cambias la altura y la anchura a la imagen y solo lo ha cambiado la primera vez, puede ser (que no tendria sentido, pero siempre hay que mirarlo) que lo tengas mal linkado si es un css externo es decir...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="QUE_ESTA_RUTA_ESTE_BIEN">
```

Si lo está, prueba a refrescar la página pulsando Shift + F5, sirve para refrescar deshabilitando la cache para esa página, es decir, igual has refrescado la página tantas veces que la cache ya la tiene guardada y no hace cambios. Tambien puedes deshabilitar la cache para esa página (mientras tengas el navegador abierto) en la consola del navegador.

Si es en Google Chrome, es pulsando F12 --> Network --> check de Disable cache.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que te haya servido, cualquier duda, seguro que algún compañero o yo mismo te respondemos!!

Answer (score 0):

En tu ejemplo estás cambiando el tamaño al div y no a la imagen.

```
<div>
    <img class="gato" src="imagen.png"/>
</div>
```

Desconozco si necesitas el position absolute y la posición en el div o en la imagen. así que eso no te lo mencionaré

Ahora es cuando puedes darle el tamaño mediante css a la imagen

```
.gato {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```